# Android app IndexOutOfBoundsException on PackedIntVector

Tags: java, android, android-studio, indexoutofboundsexception

i am developing an Android app that communicates with Bluetooth sending and receiving raw commands on byte array.

Randomly the app crashes right after i send some of this command, with the following excepcion;

```
 `Process: xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 19983
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2, 1
    at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:75)
    at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineTop(DynamicLayout.java:1010)
    at android.text.Layout.getLineBottom(Layout.java:1725)
    at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAcceleratedInner(Editor.java:2310)
    at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:2251)
    at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:2191)
    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:8852)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23901)`
```

As i understand the problem is on the PackedIntVector.java class, but its an Android class and on the stack trace there isn`t any of my app files, all are from Android classes.

Does anybody know what could be happening? The excepcion always happen right after sending a command and not always happen, but i have not found any thtat triggers it, seems "random".

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer, there was nothing to do with the bluetooth connections or something like that, it was a TextView wich i am using as log, when i empty the log to append new text for some reason it causes the exception that it posted below, so if someone is struggling with this, check if you are emptying some textview and trying to append text after or something like that.

The only thing that gived me a clue was the lines on the exception that mention the textview class;

```
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:8852)
```